# When I convert the collada from meshbasic to meshphong, parts of the collada disappear. Why is that?

Tags: three.js

When I convert the collada from meshbasic to meshphong, parts of the collada disappear. Why is that?

```
var setMaterial = function( node ) {
                                   node.material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xff0000} );
                                   console.log(node);
                                   if (node.children) {
                                     for (var i=0, thelength=node.children.length; i < thelength ; i++ ) {
                                       setMaterial(node.children[i]);
                                     }
                                   }
                                 }
                                 setMaterial(dae);
```

This works, but then this makes half of it disappear...

```
 var setMaterial = function( node ) {
                                   node.material = new THREE.MeshBasicPhong({color: 0xff0000} );
                                   console.log(node);
                                   if (node.children) {
                                     for (var i=0, thelength=node.children.length; i < thelength ; i++ ) {
                                       setMaterial(node.children[i]);
                                     }
                                   }
                                 }
                                 setMaterial(dae);
```

Answer (score 1):

i think there no material in the name THREE.MeshBasicPhong.....
change it as MeshPhongMaterial and have a try..

```
node.material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 0xff0000} );
```